I have a question about the size of the air filter
this will likely sound stupid but is a 16X20X1 filter the same as a 20X16X1 because the one I have says 20X16 but i can only find 16X20 for sale at hardware stores and even on line.

It should be the same, except one quotes WxL instead of LxW for the size.

They are the same. When changing them, make sure you have the arrow on the filter going in the direction of the air flow
